# How to achieve PageCurl(page turn) transition in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

In iOS you can use the PageCurl transition style on a UIPageViewController to have the same page curl effect as iBooks in iOS.

Is there a way to use the PageCurl transition effect on a React Native view?

Comment: this repo can be used as an alternative -https://github.com/darenju/react-flip-page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view library, which support this kind of transaction

[image]

Comment: this does not work for android

Comment: They have since removed this functionality. 

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view/issues/343