# React Native Book Animation

Tags: javascript, react-native

Are there any libraries which replicate the page turn animation in Books or is there a way to make it possible with the standard library.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162783/how-to-achieve-pagecurlpage-turn-transition-in-react-native

Comment: same question have you find any solution to it

Comment: did you find any solution

Answer (score -1):

You can use [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/) to create such an effect. It's quite simple to implement. Here's an example but do check their docs for more options.

```js
$("#flipbook").turn({
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  autoCenter: true
});
```

```html
<div id="flipbook">
  <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div>
  <div class="hard"></div>
  <div> Page 1 </div>
  <div> Page 2 </div>
  <div> Page 3 </div>
  <div> Page 4 </div>
  <div class="hard"></div>
  <div class="hard"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like this is only for HTML5 but I am looking for a solution with React Native, or is it possible to port the library to React Native?

Comment: Hi Jake, it might be possible but I don't have enough experience with React Native to say for sure.